# Can you overwrite an inner <div> with a "display: inline"

Tags: html, css, display

Given:

```
<xyz id="xyz"><div>foobar</div></xyz>
```

Is there some way, I can assign css properties to xyz, that `foobar` is displayed in an inline style, rather than in a block?

Comment: you mean something like `xyz > div { display: inline }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `display: inline;` to make your inner div displayed inline. Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/html-viewer/c782eceb16f8).

```css
#xyz div{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="xyz">
<div>foobar_1</div>
<div>foobar_2</div>
<div>foobar_3</div>
</div>
```

you may check different kind of [CSS display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)